# Python, Excel, and Charts using win32com

Tags: python, excel, charts, win32com

Python and MS Excel question - using win32com, I'm able to create a chart within Excel but i'm unable to move it within a worksheet. I've found code online to generate the chart:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
ws = xl.ActiveSheet
ws.Range('A1').FormulaR1C1 = 'X'
ws.Range('B1').FormulaR1C1 = 'Y'
ws.Range('A2').FormulaR1C1 = 1
ws.Range('A3').FormulaR1C1 = 2
ws.Range('A4').FormulaR1C1 = 3
ws.Range('B2').FormulaR1C1 = 4
ws.Range('B3').FormulaR1C1 = 5
ws.Range('B4').FormulaR1C1 = 6
#ws.Range('A1:B4').Select()
ch = ws.Shapes.AddChart().Select()
xl.ActiveChart.ChartType = c.xlXYScatterLines
xl.ActiveChart.SetSourceData(Source=ws.Range("A1:B4"))
#ch.Location(10,10) # something like this?
```

How may I move the chart within the worksheet?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the location at the time of creation of the chart `expression.AddChart(Type, Left, Top, Width, Height)` see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.addchart%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

If you don't want to embed the chart in a worksheet, you can create a chart sheet :

`wb.Worksheets.Add(Type:=xlChart)`

Caveat : Microsoft.interop.Excel not win32com, but should work.